# Swift iOS - Character animation static when game reset

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I've been building my first game in swift and really enjoying the learning process.  I am however confused why my main character `cat` who is animated to give a running appearance (two images), is only animated when the first game is played.

After the reset func the cat then stays on the one image when the game ended.  Ultimately the cat doesn't animate unless it's the first turn once the app loads up.

Here is all the code I can think that would be useful, please can someone help me here?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var cat = SKSpriteNode()
    var moving = SKNode()
    var canRestart = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.addChild(moving)

    var catTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cat1")
    catTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    var catTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Cat2")
    catTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([catTexture1, catTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    var run = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    cat = SKSpriteNode(texture: catTexture1)
    cat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.2, y: self.frame.size.height / 7.0 )
    cat.runAction(run)

    moving.addChild(cat)

}


func resetScene() {
    cat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.2, y: self.frame.size.height / 7.0 )
    cat.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    cat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = crowCategory | worldCategory;
    cat.speed = 1.0;
    cat.zRotation = 0.0;

    crows.removeAllChildren()
    trees.removeAllChildren()


    canRestart == false

    moving.speed = 1

    score = 0;
    scoreLabelNode.text = "\(score)"

}

override func  touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    if (moving.speed > 0){
        cat.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        cat.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 20))
                } else if (canRestart) {
                    self.resetScene()
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if( moving.speed > 0 ) {

        if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory || (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory){

            score++
            scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"
        }else {

            moving.speed = 0;
}
}
}
```

I've tried to re-locate all sorts of code with no real success, if anyone knows the solution that would be great, happy to post more code if anyone things it could be beneficial.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you setting the `speed` property of `moving` or `cat` to zero somewhere in your code? That will stop the animation. Also, the `canRestart == false` is a NOP.

Comment: @0x141E thanks for the reply, the only time I set `moving.speed = 0` is after contact.  If I change this the game does not pause ready for a re-start.  Is there something I need to add into my `resetScene`?

Comment: You can set `moving.paused = true` when a contact is made to pause the animation and `moving.paused = false` in `resetScene`. BTW, where are you setting `canRestart = true`?

Comment: @0x141E that worked thank you, `canRestart = true ` was listed further down.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create runAction with key.

And then remove that key in reset function like this.

Start action like this :-

```
SKAction *spriteAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:Textures timePerFrame:0.04];
repeatWalkAnimation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spriteAnimation];
[sprite runAction:repeatWalkAnimation withKey:@"animation1"];
```

Stop action like this :-

```
[sprite removeActionForKey:@"animation1"];
```

Hope this helps.